# ¿Cómo puedo corregir la apariencia de mi motor de búsqueda personalizado de Google?

Tags: css, google-search

He insertado el motor de búsqueda personalizado de Google en el footer de [mi sitio web](http://www.deiverbum.org).

Pero no se ve como debería.

Cuando lo creo, Google me dice que se verá así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en el sitio se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con todas las opciones de apariencia que se ofrecen y con todas se ve mal.

El código que se genera es este. Al parecer hay algún conflicto con mi CSS. No sé si haya alguna manera de personalizar por CSS los elementos del buscador, ya que no tengo ni idea de cuál es el elemento de mi CSS que entra en conflicto.

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '0039.....:fisw_zwcr2a';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

---

Este es el código completo que genera el script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <div id="google-search">
            <h4 class="widget_title">QUIEN BUSCA HALLA</h4><script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
            var cx = '003903249498220403564:fisw_zwcr2a';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
            })();
            </script>
    
            <div id="___gcse_0">
                <div class="gsc-control-searchbox-only gsc-control-searchbox-only-es" dir="ltr">
                    <form class="gsc-search-box gsc-search-box-tools" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-search-box">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="gsc-input">
                                        <div class="gsc-input-box " id="gsc-iw-id1">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="gs_id50" class="gstl_50 " style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td id="gs_tti50" class="gsib_a"><input autocomplete="off" type="text" size="10" class="gsc-input" name="search" title="buscar" id="gsc-i-id1" x-webkit-speech="" x-webkit-grammar="builtin:search" lang="es" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Búsqueda personalizada de Google" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: -0.0625em 0px 0px; height: 1.25em; outline: none; background-image: url(http://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_lightgrey_46x16dp.png); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-indent: 48px; background-position: left center; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></td>
    
                                                        <td class="gsib_b">
                                                            <div class="gsst_b" id="gs_st50" dir="ltr">
                                                                <a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"><span class="gscb_a" id="gs_cb50">×</span></a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
    
                                    <td class="gsc-search-button"><input type="image" src="https://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/search_box_icon.png" class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" title="buscar"></td>
    
                                    <td class="gsc-clear-button">
                                        <div class="gsc-clear-button" title="borrar resultados">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
    
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-branding">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="gsc-branding-user-defined"></td>
    
                                    <td class="gsc-branding-text">
                                        <div class="gsc-branding-text">
                                            con la tecnología de
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
    
                                    <td class="gsc-branding-img"><img src="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png" class="gsc-branding-img" srcset="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/2x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png 2x"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: *solo para descartar*, ¿tu sitio tiene algún estilo que tenga conflicto?, ¿probaste insertar este componente en una "página simple"? tal vez en la consola del navegador se pueda ver si faltó descargar algún archivo...

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave encantado de saludarte. Lo he probado en una página limpia de mi sitio y se ve bien. Debe ser algo de estilos o el hecho de que está en un widget en el footer, pero ni idea de lo que pueda ser. Borré temporalmente mi custom `css` y nada...

Comment: Favor de no usar [google]. Ya se ha eliminado del sitio en varias ocasiones y se ha realizado una solicitud de que se ponga en la lista negra. Ref. [¿Necesitamos \[google\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1030/65) y [¿Algún “malvado” que ponga a \[google\] en la lista negra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2684/65)

Comment: Lo ignoraba @Rubén. He quitado la etiqueta `google`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías simular el efecto que te está produciendo en el snippet?